# Hosting MySQL database online

Tags: python, mysql

Got a project from school, using Python and MySQL. There are a total of 4 members in my group.
When importing MySQL.connector in python we have to input
MySQL.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root"........)

Is it possible to host it online and work together on it?

Comment: There are commercial services like Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Available

If it is the same network, you can use it by designating the host as privateIP.

It is recommended to create and use an account for each user.